# Flutter Build failed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-build, flutter-run

While building and running the Flutter mobile application with flutter --version

Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c5a4b4029c (3 days ago) • 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0

I am getting the below error.

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/Applications/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:83:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Applications/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const Scaffold({
^^^^^^^^
/Applications/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Applications/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /Applications/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.0.0+1/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:101:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/Applications/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieAudioControllerProvider)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /Applications/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.0/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
  context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
  ^^^^^^
  /Applications/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
  ^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Applications/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Applications/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

On running flutter doctor no errors are shown. Based on some references even tried switching the flutter channel to beta, master, and dev but the issue still occurs. With the downgrade of the flutter version as well, I am unable to resolve this. The application was working well before and all of sudden this happened.

Please help me in resolving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I assume, one of your package causing the problem, I think It's `chewie_player`.Try using latest version of it, Go to pub dev, and copy the dependence, paste it in `.yaml` file in place of older dependence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using the chewie_player directly in the pubspec.yaml file. What to do in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by not "directly using" ? You copied from the source file?

Comment: No @xahid. I mean to say there are some libraries that I used in my application that uses chewis_player. I have not included it directly in pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: then you have to update those libraries, since flutter 2.0 released, there are many conflict/error according it. It's the best try, update all of your library / packages to latest version and upgrade your project to flutter 2.0. Hope that will help.